# asp communication with flex

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex

i was developed one .net application. It contains flash animation in one of the asp pages. And i need to write action script code for playing and pausing that swf file. I am using flex builder3. However how can i execute the asp application from  flex builder? How can i load asp page into mxml file? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you *need* to run asp code in your flex app, I recommend http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/

But, if you need to write code in your asp app to control the swf, you'd be looking at fabridge, which you'll find in your sdk frameworks directory (C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.2.0\frameworks\javascript\fabridge).